# Integral asymptotic approximation

Tags: perturbation-theory

I am trying to attain a two-term approximation for the following integral as $m$ goes to $1$ from below: $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi /2}\frac{\mathrm d\theta }{\sqrt{1-(m^2)\cdot\sin(\theta)^2 }}.$$
So far I am struggling to get the approximation because I have not been able to put my hand on a proper change of variable.

I would appreciate any comments.

Comment: If `m  goes to 1` and `m<1` (2 terms) with Mathematica I have:$$\frac{1}{64} \left(2 \left(-15+m (22-54 \ln (2))+87 \ln (2)+m^2 (-7+15 \ln (2))\right)+\left(-29+18 m-5 m^2\right) \ln
   \left((-1+m)^2\right)\right)$$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk. Could you give the syntax ? Thanks :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Try: `Simplify[AsymptoticIntegrate[1/Sqrt[
    1 - (m^2)*Sin[x]^2], {x, 0, Pi/2}, {m, 1, 2}, 
    Assumptions -> m > 0] // Re // ComplexExpand, 
 Assumptions -> m > 0]`

Answer (score 2):

This is just the complete elliptic intagral of the first kind, thus
$$
I = K(m) =  - \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\Gamma ^2 \!\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}{{\Gamma ^2 (n + 1)}}(1 - m^2 )^n (\log (1 - m^2 ) + a_n )} 
$$
as $m \to 1-0$, where $a_0 =2\log 2$ and
$$
a_{n + 1}  = a_n  + \frac{4}{{(2n + 1)(2n + 2)}} \quad (n\geq 0).
$$

Comment: how is it possible to get the approximation by splitting the interval into a subinterval which contributes "locally" and another which contributes "globally" ?

Comment: I am not sure how to get this expansion directly from the integral for $K(m)$. A derivation using differential equations is given in Cayley's *An Elementary Treatise on Elliptic Functions*, p. 52-54.